# Add Plus to dropdown with django

Tags: django

Any ideia how to implement form field with plus icon to add ? Like form in django admin.
[image]

Thank You

Comment: it's  a selectbox   with an icon which on click event  pops a create form for the foreign key, so what is the question ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i mean. How to implement to my own form?

Comment: in your form   in the selectbox  add an icon with the link to the createview you want  and the with modal ajax  on the click of the icon you will load the create form partial

Comment: Is there django method that can handle this?

Comment: nope you have to do it yourself but there is a good tutorial on how to do this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html i refer to this everytime i need ajax + django.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [`ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields). For example:

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Car, Driver


@admin.register(Car)
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = [
        "driver",
    ]


@admin.register(Driver)
class DriverAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = [
        "name",
    ]
```